# SQL reference to alias name in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm currently working on a query which takes all the relevant data AND stock levels within a query, rather than looping over the stock levels separately. So far I have managed to obtain those stock levels by doing this:

```
<cfquery datasource="datasource" name="get">
    Select *,
    (
        Select IsNull(Sum(stocklevel))
        From itemstock
        Where item_id = itemstock_itemid
    ) As stock_count
    From items
    Where item_id = #URL.item_id#
</cfquery>
```

Now the term I tried adding after the "Where" clause is this:

```
And get.stock_count > 0
```

This however just throws an error and says it is not a valid field (which makes sense) im wondering, how do i reference back to that Sum total?

Comment: Not related to your question, but IsNull(Sum(stocklevel) is missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: On my example above yes, but in my actual query no. I'll correct that now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: This is not a CF question, so removed the CF-centric tags. But might help if you tag it with which dialect of SQL you're using (Oracle, etc).

Comment: It is CF related as ColdFusion is the server software i am using.

Comment: Mate, the SQL is not processed by CF. It's just passed to the DB driver. All CF sees is "a string". CF plays no part in the answer to your question. It's *not* a CF question and more than it's a Windows/*nix question because you happen to be running on one of those OSes. That's why I untagged it.

Comment: I know it's not a general CF question, and i know it is passed to the database driver. But i've posted question like these before and i've been asked about what server software i'm using, so i find it easier to simply include it and be done with.

Comment: OK mate. If that makes you feel happy.

Comment: @LeeB - With query questions, it is a good idea to always include your database type *and* version in the tags, rather than just `sql`. Reason being, a lot of SQL syntax is vendor specific, and even that can vary by version. For example, the above might apply to SQL Server, Sybase or Oracle. With this specific query it does not matter, but it frequently makes a difference in the syntax needed. So including your DBMS saves time and ensures you get an accurate answer the first time around.

Comment: @Leigh fair enough that's understandable. I'll add that in now to add some clarity to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference an alias, use a derived table:

```
select * from 
(Select *,
(
    Select IsNull(Sum(stocklevel), 0)
    From itemstock
    Where item_id = itemstock_itemid
) As stock_count
From items
Where item_id = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.item_id#">
) derived_table
where stock_count > 0
```

Note that my query param tag is not complete.  It needs a datatype, but you can do that.

Comment: Nice! This did the trick.. For the sake of it being the correct answer, could you please add a little detail to how it works? Just so in future i'm not creating it because i know it works but because i know HOW it works.

Comment: A [derived table](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDerivedTables.aspx) allows you to use a query as if it were a physical table. Essentially you wrap the query in parenthesis and give it an alias. Then you can use it in a `FROM` clause, just like any regular table ie `SELECT someTableAlias.* FROM   ( .. some sql query here... ) someTableAlias`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference 'get.' inside the query. I think if you just reference stock_count you should be fine?

Comment: I've tried this, doesn't work unfortunately.. Basically i want to figure out stock levels whilst gaining the information of a product and then determine if it's stock level is greater than zero.. If i do this when looping the query i end up with blank spaces where a product WOULD have been but its stock level was 0. If you can see my issue now..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to alias in the way that you tried. But this still can be solved at SQL level, without involving CF. E.g:

```
WITH Stocks AS 
( Select *,
  (
    Select IsNull(Sum(stocklevel))
    From itemstock
    Where item_id = itemstock_itemid
  ) As stock_count
  From items
  Where item_id = #URL.item_id#
)
SELECT * FROM Stocks WHERE stock_count > 0
```

Alternatively you could of course use CF's query of queries, so having your original query, you would go for something like:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="get_only_what_i_need">
select *
from get
where stock_count > 0
</cfquery>
```

First solution is much preferred, as it keeps all the querying at DB level.

Comment: I like the idea of using With As, this separates the "false table" into a separate entity which as you've shown is then queried for anything with `stock_count` greater than 0. Good answer but Dan was quicker with the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give it a new name:

```
...
Select IsNull(Sum(stocklevel)) as SumTotal
...
And stock_count.SumTotal > 0
```

Comment: This isn't very informative and doesn't solve the problem i have.. I need details as how to back reference to the sum total within the subquery, because this query selects details about the product too, the subquery simply handles stock but it needs to only select products in which the subquery value returns greater than 0.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. Have you tried ``and stock_count > 0`` (without the ``get.``)?